# Unable to import PyAudio package

Tags: python, pyaudio

seeing this error on executing the program:

```
Could not import the PyAudio C module 'pyaudio._portaudio'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/anandsingh/Desktop/openAI_API/Web_apps/Transcriber/app.py", line 4, in <module>
    import pyaudio
  File "/Users/anandsingh/opt/anaconda3/envs/transcriberenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyaudio/__init__.py", line 111, in <module>
    import pyaudio._portaudio as pa
**ImportError:** dlopen(/Users/anandsingh/opt/anaconda3/envs/transcriberenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyaudio/_portaudio.cpython-311-darwin.so, 0x0002): symbol not found in flat namespace '_PaMacCore_SetupChannelMap'
```

```
pip install pyaudio
```

runs successfully but seeing above error on execution.

Comment: Looks like you're using not on `windows`. see: https://pypi.org/project/PyAudio/. You'll need to install other libraries on `macos` and `GNU/Linux`.